# How to download Azure bot source code from azure portal

Tags: azure, botframework, chat

I am developing a chatbot using Language Studio and the bot framework composer.
I have tested it with "test in web chat" in Azure and confirmed that it can answer questions successfully.

I would like to download the source code to customize the chatbot, but there is no "build" page and I cannot find "Download bot source code" on the "overview" page.
Where can I download the current Azure bot source code?

references website
[How to Download QnA Maker Bot Source Code from Azure Portal?](https://jd-bots.com/2021/06/24/how-to-download-qna-maker-bot-source-code-from-azure-portal/)

- Accessed the created azure bot and checked the overview page
- I accessed the azure bot I created and looked for the build page, but could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the provided information, the issue might be due to `type` of Bot Service.

As the `Web App Bot` will have the option and `Azure Bot` don't have it.

[image]
[image]

As mentioned in question you are using `Bot Framework Composer`.
Then you can get the `source code` from `Bot project location` in your local system.
[image]
The location contains the souce code.
[image]

For more details related to publish a Web App Bot please check this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/provision-and-publish-a-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned,csharp#publish-your-bot-to-azure)

You can check the [BotBuilder QnA Sample Code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/12.customQABot)  and modify it as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Idid'nt difference between "Azure Bot" and "Web App Bot".
Download from bot framework composer and edit the source code.